# echo is not showing anything on output browser side

Tags: php, mysql, apache, echo

This should be printed on output browser side:

```
$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></br>
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /></br>
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /></br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /></br>
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;
echo $form;
```

But there is nothing.

This is my full code, which I should have added in the first place.

```
<?php
    require("config.php");
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if($email1 == $email2) {
        if($pass1 == $pass2) {
    //All good. Nastavi broo.

        $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
        $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
        $email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
        $pass1 = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
        $pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);

    }else{
      echo "Sorry, your password is not corrext.";
      exit();
    }
}else{
  echo "Sorry!";
}

$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></br>
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /></br>
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /></br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /></br>
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;
echo $form;

}
?>
```

Comment: view source, do you see the php?

Comment: I tested, the code is working fine, you an issue with something else (ensure you are writing this within php tags though.)

Comment: did you click on submit? *grin*

Comment: I had that one lined up too @Dagon but will give them the 5 min. benefit of the doubt.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, it's just "you". so, do respond to comments up here.

Comment: *"view source, do you see the php?"* - Stars @Dagon stars.

Comment: Your form will only echo once you click the submit button.

Comment: place it outside your conditional statement after your last `}`.

Comment: @Dagon Nope, wasn't it. It was indeed a bracing thing, which I caught ;-) gotta love IDE's *huh?!*

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form will only appear once you click the submit button because it is set inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` conditional statement. Therefore, you need to move your last brace `}` above `$form = <<<EOT`.

```
} // it belongs here instead of below echo $form;
$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></br>
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /></br>
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /></br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /></br>
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;

?>
```

and make sure you are accessing it as `http://localhost/file.php` and not as `c://file.php`

---

EDIT:

Here's a rewrite:

```
<?php
require("config.php");
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

if($email1 == $email2) {
    if($pass1 == $pass2) {
//All good. Nastavi broo.

$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
$email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
$pass1 = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
$pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);


}else{
  echo "Sorry, your password is not corrext.";
  exit();
}
}else{
  echo "Sorry!";
}

} // brace for submit conditional

$form = <<<EOT
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /></br>
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /></br>
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /></br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /></br>
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
</form>
EOT;
echo $form;

?>
```

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended. If you intend on going LIVE with this, do read the following.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: form in C:\xampp\htdocs\phoenixproject\register.php on line 47

Comment: @AmarMuratović ok reload it. that brace should have been higher up, sorry about that.

Comment: @AmarMuratović I made up a rewrite under **EDIT: Here's a rewrite:**.

Comment: Thank you men soo much! I really apreciate :D

Comment: @AmarMuratović You're welcome, glad I could help. *Cheers* and you could mark it as solved also ;-) so others won't be tempted to post more answers.